# How can I modify this code to turn the button red when it's pressed?

Tags: function-construction, button

How can I modify this code to turn the button red when it's pressed?

```
DynamicModule[{buttonState1 = False}, 
 Column[{Button[Dynamic@If[buttonState1, "Pressed", "Not Pressed"], 
    buttonState1 = Not@buttonState1, 
    Appearance -> 
     Dynamic@If[
       buttonState1, {"Pressed", 
        "Method" -> {"Active" -> Directive[EdgeForm[], Red]}}, 
       Automatic], Method -> "Queued"], 
   Dynamic@If[buttonState1, "Button is Pressed", 
     "Button is Not Pressed"]}]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 DynamicModule[{buttonState1 = False}, 
 Column[{Button[Dynamic@If[buttonState1, "Pressed", "Not Pressed"], 
    buttonState1 = Not@buttonState1, 
    Background -> Dynamic@If[buttonState1, Lighter@Red, Automatic], 
    Method -> "Queued"], 
   Dynamic@If[buttonState1, "Button is Pressed", 
     "Button is Not Pressed"]}]]
```